# Django DRF Serializer slice amount in list of nested field based on user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to ask how to slice a nested lists in DRF.
I have models Store, Manager, Products.

Serializer returns store object with a nested fields.

What I want to do is to slice the values, to NOT return all, just to return Store, with top 3 managers and top3 products for each manager. And to do this based on User, if this is supervisor, then return full list, if manager, then only limited.

I guess anyway I need to use different serializer for each use type, but how to slice nested value, that only return top 3?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SerializerMethodField`.

```py
class ManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ("store",)
        model = User
    def get_store(self, user):
        if user.is_supervisor:
            return AllStore
        else:
            return LimitedStore
```